# Need to return a True value is the sum of identical values that share an identical value is odd

Tags: excel

I need to determine if each client from a given company ID is an odd-man-out so to speak.  I'm leaning towards finding out if the sum running total of "Company ID's" is odd, AND if they share the same date, then TRUE-

So as we add one row at a time for this data set:

```
InvoiceableDate CompanyID  Single client from this company?
4/30/2012 4:00  30003134   
4/30/2012 4:00  30003134   
4/30/2012 4:00  1000009602 
4/30/2012 4:00  1075000    
4/30/2012 4:00  30003134  
4/30/2012 4:00  30003134
```

The result would be:

```
InvoiceableDate CompanyID Single client from this company?
4/30/2012 4:00  30003134  True
```

followed by:

```
InvoiceableDate CompanyID  Single client from this company?
4/30/2012 4:00  30003134   False
4/30/2012 4:00  30003134   False
```

followed by:

```
InvoiceableDate CompanyID  Single client from this company?
4/30/2012 4:00  30003134   False 
4/30/2012 4:00  30003134   False 
4/30/2012 4:00  1000009602 True
```

Followed by:

```
InvoiceableDate CompanyID  Single client from this company?
4/30/2012 4:00  30003134   False
4/30/2012 4:00  30003134   False 
4/30/2012 4:00  1000009602 True 
4/30/2012 4:00  1075000    True
```

Followed By:

```
InvoiceableDate CompanyID  Single client from this company?
4/30/2012 4:00  30003134   False
4/30/2012 4:00  30003134   False 
4/30/2012 4:00  1000009602 True 
4/30/2012 4:00  1075000    True
4/30/2012 4:00  30003134   True
```

And Finally:

```
InvoiceableDate CompanyID  Single client from this company?
4/30/2012 4:00  30003134   False
4/30/2012 4:00  30003134   False 
4/30/2012 4:00  1000009602 True 
4/30/2012 4:00  1075000    True
4/30/2012 4:00  30003134   False
4/30/2012 4:00  30003134   False
```

Sorry for the long post, I am building my vocabulary to explain things correctly.

Comment: okay that formatting didn't work at all- let me try again

Answer (score 0):

For what I could figure from your question, let's say your data is in cols A and B.

The column C, your astatus, should be:

```
=IF(MOD(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$1000;A2;$B$2:$B$1000;B2);2)<>0;TRUE;FALSE)
```

So, if the Timestamp AND CompanyID matches, the count is increased.
Then, if the total counter is odd, it returns TRUE.